# Displaying images in php error

Tags: php, html

I am using this code but it is giving me errors. How do I display the images in a table using php?

```
echo "<td>"."<img src=\"=View.php?image_id=$row['Id']>\""."</td>";
```

I am getting a syntax error, how can I fix this?

```
 The error that I get is -  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 
T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\gallery_test\listImages.php on line 45
```

Thank You

Comment: You have misplaced on of the quotes directly after the url and there is one `=` too many. Also, why are you concatenating the string? Makes it look messy imho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break it down:

```
echo "<td>"
 . "<img src=\"=View.php?image_id=$row['Id']>\""
 . "</td>";
```

First we need to fix the misplaced `=`. After that, we need to fix the misplaced quote. Finally, wrap `$row['Id']` in brackets to fix the syntax error. It should now look like this:

```
echo "<td>"
 . "<img src=\"View.php?image_id={$row['Id']}\">"
 . "</td>";
```

If you'll write it like this, you'd have less of a mess and it fixes the error. Clean and simple.

```
echo "<td><img src=\"View.php?image_id={$row['Id']}\"></td>";
```

When placing variables in strings it's recommended to wrap them in brackets to avoid syntax errors like these but also to keep your code looking clean.

Answer (score 0):

Try as

```
echo '<td><img src="View.php?image_id='.$row['Id'].'"></td>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, You have string concatenation issue.

```
echo "<td><img src='View.php?image_id=".$row['Id']."' ></td>";
```